# How to search with mongooseJs with nested logic when all parameter are not guaranteed?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I want to search in a collection with two parameters and there is no guarantee that both parameters will be available anyone of them can be missing I want to ignore it and search only with one parameter.
I also want to search in two fields with the second parameter using $or.

My Code
`NodeJs Express Mongoose`

```
    colec.find({
        $and: [{
            'address.zip': req.query.p,
            $or: [{ 'name': req.query.n }, { 'tags': req.query.n }]
        }]
    }, function (err, foundProfiles) {
//Some Code
})
```

my code before tags search

```
var terms = {};
if (req.query.q) {
    var name = req.query.q;
}
if (req.query.p) {
    terms['address.zip'] = req.query.p;
}

colec.find(terms, function(err, foundProfiles){
  //some code
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this after searching for a long time.

```
var dbQueries = [];
if (req.query.q) {
    var search = req.query.q;
    dbQueries.push({
        $or: [
            { name: search },
            { tags: search },
        ]
    });
}
if (req.query.p) {
    dbQueries.push({ 'address.zip': req.query.p });
}
dbQueries = { $and: dbQueries }

Collection.find(dbQueries, function (err, foundProfiles) {
    //some code
});
```